# Como conectar 2 API por medio de otra API

Tags: php, javascript, api

Muy buenas

Tengo un usuario (1) con una lista de canciones
Tengo un Proveedor (2) hace de puente o intermediario
Por ultimo tengo un servicio(3) de Musica con una API

Necesito que el usuario (1) haga una peticion (API Post) enviando la lista de canciones en un JSON al proveedor (2) y este proveedor las publique en el servidor (3) consumiendo el API (Put)

como puedo hacer esto con JavaScript o Php ?  alguna sugerencia.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola,  temo decirlo,  pero las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son aceptadas por la comunidad de stackoverflow,  si deseas recomendaciones o sugerencias creo que google o yahoo son buenas opciones, porfavor lee [ask].

Comment: Joda no molesten y contestenle la duda al men!!!